# How to wait for function which has Observable inside it

Tags: typescript, observable

```
 async  ngOnInit(){
    console.log('ngOnInit');
    var p1 =  this.Promisefun();
    Promise.all([p1]).then(()=>{
      this.PrintAfterAll();
    });

  }

  PrintAfterAll(){
    console.log('PrintAfterAll');
  }
 async  Promisefun(){
    const observable = new Observable<string>(observer => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next('value1');
        observer.next('value2');
        observer.next('value3');
        observer.complete();
      },100);
    });

    observable.subscribe( result => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
```

---

output

PrintAfterAll
app.component.ts:36 value1
app.component.ts:36 value2
app.component.ts:36 value3

--Expected Output 
app.component.ts:36 value1
app.component.ts:36 value2
app.component.ts:36 value3
PrintAfterAll

Want to invoke PrintAfterAll function after Promisefun completes all subscription inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert Observable to Promise with [toPromise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise) function

In your example you would have to append `Promisefun` with `return observable.toPromise();`

```js
async function ngOnInit() {


  var p1 = this.Promisefun();

  Promise.all([p1]).then(() => {
    this.PrintAfterAll();
  });

}

function PrintAfterAll() {
  console.log('PrintAfterAll');
}

async function Promisefun() {

  const observable = new rxjs.Observable(observer => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next('value1');
      observer.next('value2');
      observer.next('value3');
      observer.complete();
    }, 100);
  });

  observable.subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });

  return observable.toPromise();
}

ngOnInit();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much !